# Does the version of buildTools and buildSdk used to build third-party libraries to successfully build my project?

Tags: android, gradle, travis-ci

Specifically I am interested in this issue if you use Travis CI. Namely, if in travis.yml file specify versions of buildTools's and buildSdk, for example more recent than was used to build third-party libraries.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you use newer versions you risk deprecated code. Could you provide an example, though?

Comment: My question is mostly theoretical in nature, I had problems with the support libraries, so I'm interested about other libraries

Comment: The support libraries version do matter and should match closely to the compileSdk. I can't remember if the build tools affect that